# Display 20 graphs based on four columns using subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

There is a dataframe with Date, Type, Price and Location columns. It is necessary to build graphs (each - on a separate picture) of the dependence of Price on Date for each Type - this is done, I get 10 graphs:

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.read_csv('ap-northeast-1.csv', parse_dates = True, names=['Date','Type','OS', 'Location', 'Price'])
da = dat[dat.OS == 'Windows']
del da['OS']

date = []
for d in da["Date"]:
    d = str(d)
    date.append(d[:10])
da["Date"] = date

df = da.loc[da.Type.str.startswith('i')]
(df
 .set_index("Date")
 .groupby("Type")
 .apply(lambda x: x[["Price"]].plot(grid=True, title=x.name)))
```

You also need to display these graphs in columns using subplots. Each column should contain graphs related to its Location (That is, there should be 20 graphs, which are located in the columns. The quantity of columns depends on the number of 'Location'.). How to do it?

[Dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lNZHzYBdYqK_Ip3G-eNNUzcfiLgWDgNE/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

The groupby is the key,  just group by both then allow subplots.
This will get you the 20 you need.

```
(df
 .set_index("Date")
 .groupby(['Type','Location'])
 .apply(lambda x: x[["Price"]].plot(grid=True, \
                                    title=[x.name], \
                                    subplots=True)))
```

Comment: In your code all 20 graphs are displayed in one column, and you need the graphs of each Location to be in its own column.